# Time series translation into Keras input

Tags: input, keras, time-series

I have timeseries data (ECG). I have annotations for blocks of 30seconds. 
each block has 1000 data points. We have 500 of those data blocks.

The target, the annotations are e.g. in range 1 to 5.

To be clear please see Figure
[image]

**About X-DATA**

How translate that into the Keras notation for input data [Samples,timesteps, features]?

My guess:

- Samples=Blocks (500)
- timesteps=values(1000)
- features= ECG as itselve (1)

resulting in [500,1000,1]

**About Y-Data(target)**

My target or y data would result in 
[500,1,1]

after one hot encoding it would be 
[500,5,1]

The problem is that Keras expect the X and y data to be of same dimensions. But increasing my ydata to 1000 per timestep would not make sense to me.

Thanks for your help

p.s. cannot answer directly as I am with my parent in law. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're thinking about y incorrectly. From my understanding based on you're graph.
y actually is (500, 5) after one hot encoding. That is, for every block there is a single outcome.

Also there is no need for X and y to have the same dimensions in Keras (unless you have a seq2seq requirement which is not the case here).

What we do want is the model to give us a probability distribution over
the possible labels for each block, and that we'll achieve using a softmax
on the last (`Dense`) layer.

Here is how I simulated your problem:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM


# using eye doesn't capture one-hot but works for the example
series = np.random.rand(500, 1000, 1)
labels = np.eye(500, 5)

inp = Input(shape=(1000, 1))
lstm = LSTM(128)(inp)
out = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(series, labels)
```

Comment: Dear putonspectacles, thanks a lot. 
To be clear, was my assumption for the X-data correct? And true, I actually have Y of (500,1) after one hot encoding. I added another dimension as I thought it had to have the same dimensions as the X-data. For the first test, I used the sequential model with a softmax layer for the output. ...
.

Comment: ... There, I got a value error telling me that it expected same dimensions as the input (now with y beeing [500,5] and output set to 5). This started my confusion. Is there a differnece using sigmoid to not raise the value error? Thanks again for your help. Happy easter fesivities, if you celabrate them.

Comment: Your assumption about X seems fine. Sigmoid gives the probability over the classes, so it outputs  an (?, 5) array in this case and that is the shape of the target y's. so we dont get a value error.