# Keras input value error

Tags: python, keras, time-series

I have ECG data which are in tensor-form of (samples, timesteps, features) with e.g. (2464,15000,1).

I aim to classify labels in the range 1 to 5. I one hot encoded the target to have the dimensions (2464,5).

Before I start with LSTM I wanted to try a basic approach. With following sequential model:

```
 def build_model():  
        model = models.Sequential()                 
        model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu',input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]))) 
        model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))           
        model.add(layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

        model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop',
                       metrics=['mae'])
        return model

    model=build_model()
    history=model.fit(X_train,
                      y_train,
                      epochs=20,
                      batch_size=512,
                      validation_data=(X_val,y_val))
```

Unfortunately, I get a value error:

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 113, in _standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_13 to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (2464, 5)

I searched for other topics with the problem. Most of the case, the output layer does not fit the expected targets, in my case 5. So that should be correct. The other issue was often that the target was not one hot encoded. But that is also done. The error tells me to have three dimensions (based on the input?). But if I add one dimension to gain a target dimension of (2464,5,1), the ValueError change, expecting the same dimension as the input data, while I have to reduce it to the y-target with the softmax layer.

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_23 to have shape (15000, 1) but got array with shape (5, 1)

I get confused. Could you give me a hint?

Extra: I also tried to flatten the input, but get also a (different) ValueError (...shape (1,) but got array with shape (5,)). Is flattening here the correct approach?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is actually your **loss function**. Since you already have 1-hot encoded **y** vectors then you should not be using the sparse categorical cross entropy, but rather you should use categorical cross entropy. Try this

## Categorical cross entropy

Let's just make some dummy data for dimensions sake.

```
X_train = np.zeros((2464, 150, 1))
y_train = np.zeros((2464,))

X_val = np.zeros((2464, 150, 1))
y_val = np.zeros((2464,))

X_train_r = X_train.reshape(2464,150,)
X_val_r = X_val.reshape(2464,150,)
input_shape = (150,)

print(X_train_r.shape)
print(X_val_r.shape)
```

> (2464, 150) 
>  (2464, 150)

Now we will get our one hot encoded outputs for our labels.

```
num_classes = 5
# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices. This uses 1 hot encoding.
y_train_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_val_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val, num_classes)

print(y_train_binary.shape)
print(y_val_binary.shape)
```

> (2464, 5) 
> (2464, 5)

Now we will make our model as follows

```
model = Sequential()                 
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)) 
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))           
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history=model.fit(X_train_r,
                  y_train_binary,
                  epochs=5,
                  batch_size=8,
                  validation_data=(X_val_r, y_val_binary))
```

This will work for you.

## Sparse categorical cross entropy

If you want to use sparse categorical cross entropy then you should not use 1-hot encoded labels. Like this

```
X_train = np.zeros((2464, 150, 1))
y_train = np.zeros((2464,))

X_val = np.zeros((2464, 150, 1))
y_val = np.zeros((2464,))

X_train_r = X_train.reshape(2464,150,)
X_val_r = X_val.reshape(2464,150,)
input_shape = (150,)

num_classes = 5

model = Sequential()                 
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)) 
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))           
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop',
                       metrics=['mae'])

model.summary()

history=model.fit(X_train_r,
                  y_train,
                  epochs=5,
                  batch_size=8,
                  validation_data=(X_val_r, y_val))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder. Do I always need a channel dimension? As I am working with time series data which is only a 3D tensor. Does Keras not detect this? So If I understand correctly, I would just add a "fake" channel of 1 to the back. Creating a 4d tensor out of a 3D tensor.

Comment: OR is this model approach I choose not suitable for time series. If I want to use just this classic dense layer approach, do I have to flatten my input data? Thanks

Comment: Can you share a small sample of your data so that I can see how to correctly shape it please?

Comment: As the data shape is already a problem for a while, may I redirect you to another post I created where I explain the data with a nice image. That might make more sense than the actual data. The data amount is simplified but the principle is the same (just compare the first line of this post to the other post). :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577361/time-series-translation-into-keras-input

Comment: So you have 500 blocks, each with 1000 values? And each of these blocks have a label y?

Comment: Exactly, to translate it to here, I would have 2464 blocks with each 15000 values. Each block has a single label y (in the range of 1 to 5).

Comment: Ok I found the problem now. I'll append my answer. The method you will use will depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @FloridaMan Check the new answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question: It does not work if I use it with (2464,150,1) and input _shape: (150,1). I ask, as I later want to also use different input data of the same dimensions but with multiple features. But then changing the input dimension to (150,num_features), might not work, or is this only a problem of the 1 in (150,1)?

Comment: Yah this is only a problem of the output. It is not affected by the input. Your loss function does not see your input, only the output. So you need to pick a loss function which is compatible with the output size.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks for all your time and effort. Have a nice life.